# How can I find the link URL by link text with XPath?

Tags: xml, xhtml, xpath

I have a well formed [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) page.
I want to find the destination URL of a link when I have the text that is linked.

Example

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">programming questions site</a>
<a href="http://cnn.com">news</a>
```

I want an [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression such that if given `programming questions site` it will give `http://stackoverflow.com` and if I give it `news` it will give `http://cnn.com`.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Should be something similar to:

```
//a[text()='text_i_want_to_find']/@href
```

Comment: will I ever learn xpath? when I see a query it is so obvious and easy to understand... but I am never able to write one on my own

Comment: @flybywire If you read this Stanford's free Introduction to Databases course has a good section on XML and XPath.

Comment: Instead of text(), you can use ".=", for example //a[.='Register here']

Comment: What if I don't know the text? Can I select the nodes which contains `http` or certain keyword?

Answer (score 80):

Too late for you, but for anyone else with the same question...

```xml
//a[contains(text(), 'programming')]/@href
```

Of course, 'programming' can be any text fragment.

Comment: This one is more generalized. Good share

Comment: This is case sensitive. Can I ignore the case here?

Answer (score 10):

```xml
//a[text()='programming quesions site']/@href
```

which basically identifies an anchor node `<a>` that has the text you want, and extracts the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

Think of the phrase in the square brackets as a WHERE clause in SQL.

So this query says, "select the "href" attribute (@) of an "a" tag that appears anywhere (//), but only where (the bracketed phrase) the textual contents of the "a" tag is equal to 'programming questions site'".

Comment: Hi Peter, do you have any tutorial site to learn xpath query?

Comment: a detailed blog on xpaths: https://sandeepsamudrala.hashnode.dev/know-all-about-xpath-in-one-go

Answer (score 4):

For case insensitive contains, use the following:

```xml
//a[contains(translate(text(),'PROGRAMMING','programming'), 'programming')]/@href
```

translate converts capital letters in PROGRAMMING to lower case programming.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.

Comment: "Thanks" wasn't my "answer". I was, in a way, giving credit to an answer above that I improved on.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using html agility pack use getattributeValue:

```
$doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='className']/div[@class='InternalClass']/a[@class='InternalClass']").GetAttributeValue("href","")
```