# How to identify subtly different HTML anchor tags with XPath?

Tags: xpath

I have two anchor tags that differ only because the second one does not contain the word "`Report`" in the anchor text or in the address link.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/data/invoices/2010/10/invoices-report---tuesday-october-12.html">Invoices Report - Tuesday, October 12</a>

<a href="http://www.example.com/data/invoices/2010/10/invoices---tuesday-october-12.html">Invoices - Tuesday, October 12</a>
```

How would you identify the first link with XPath and avoid identifying the second?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two short solutions. :)

Comment: Try this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915338/xpath-find-link-url-by-link-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would you identify the first link
>   with XPath and avoid identifying the
>   second?

There are many ways of doing this:

```
//a[contains(., 'Report')]
```

or

```
//a[contains(@href,'report')]
```

Both of these XPath expressions select the first `a` element and don't select the second `a` element.