# How to obtain href values from a div using xpath?

Tags: html, css, xpath

I have a div like this:

```
    <div class="widget-archive-monthly widget-archive widget"> 
    <h3 class="widget-header">Monthly <a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/archives.html">Archives</a></h3> 
    <div class="widget-content"> 
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/10/">October 2010</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/09/">September 2010</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/08/">August 2010</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/07/">July 2010</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/06/">June 2010</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/05/">May 2010</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/04/">April 2010</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/03/">March 2010</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/02/">February 2010</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/01/">January 2010</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2009/12/">December 2009</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2009/11/">November 2009</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2009/10/">October 2009</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2009/09/">September 2009</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2009/08/">August 2009</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2009/07/">July 2009</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2009/06/">June 2009</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2009/05/">May 2009</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2009/04/">April 2009</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2009/03/">March 2009</a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2009/02/">February 2009</a></li> 
        </ul> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the href values inside the `widget-content` div.

How would I target these links using xpath and ignore any other link on the page such as the one for "Archives" so that I end up just with these values:

```
        http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/10/
        http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/09/
        http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/08/
        http://myblog.com/blogs/my_name/2010/07/
        ... etc ...
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
//div[@class="widget-content"]//a/@href
```

That should give you the href values of links that are ONLY inside the `widget-content` DIV.

Answer (score -2):

relative answer = [XPath: find link URL by link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915338/xpath-find-link-url-by-link-text)

```
"//a/@href"
```

Comment: OP is asking for all href attribute values inside a specific div and not in the whole DOM.