# How do I search through a string for a particular hyperlink in Visualbasic.net?

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a written a program which downloads a webpage's source but now I want to search the source for a particular link I know the link is written like this:

```
<a href="/internet/A2/"><b>Geographical Survey Work</b></a>
```

Is there anyway of using "Geographical Survey Work" as criteria to retrieve the link? The code I am using to download the source to a string is this:

```
Dim sourcecode As String = ((New Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://examplesite.com"))
```

So just to clarify I want to type into an input box "Geographical Survey Work" for instance and "/internet/A2" to popup in a messagebox? I think it can be done using a regex, but that's a bit beyond me. Any help would be great.

Comment: You can use HtmlAgilityPack API.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html

Comment: related: [XPath: find link URL by link text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915338/xpath-find-link-url-by-link-text)

Answer (score 0):

With HTMLAgilityPack:

```
Dim vsPageHTML As String = "<html>... your webpage HTML code ...</html>"
Dim voHTMLDoc.LoadHtml(vsPageHTML) : vsPageHTML = ""
Dim vsURI As String = ""
Dim voNodes As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = voHTMLDoc.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
If Not IsNothing(voNodes) Then
    For Each voNode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In voNodes
        If voNode.innerHTML.toLower() = "<b>geographical survey work</b>" Then
            vsURI = voNode.GetAttributeValue("href", "")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
voNodes = Nothing : voHTMLDoc = Nothing
```

Do whatever you want with vsURI.
You might need to tweak the code a bit as I'm writing free-hand.