# Extracting specific page links from a <a href tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract all the links from this page: http://kern.humdrum.org/search?s=t&keyword=Haydn

I am getting all these links this way:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://kern.humdrum.org/search?s=t&keyword=Haydn'

#opening up connecting, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)

# put all the content in a variable
page_html = uClient.read()

#close the internet connection
uClient.close()

#It does my HTML parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# Grab all of the links
containers = page_soup.findAll('a', href=True)
#print(type(containers))

for container in containers:
    link = container
    #start_index = link.index('href="') 
    print(link)
    print("---")
    #print(start_index)
```

part of my output is:
[image]

Notice that it is returning several links but I really want all the ones with >Someting. (For example, ">Allegro" and "Allegro vivace" and so forth).

I am having a hard time getting the following type of output (example of the image):
"Allegro - http://kern.ccarh.org/cgi-bin/ksdata?location=users/craig/classical/beethoven/piano/sonata&file=sonata01-1.krn&format=info"

In other words, at this point, I have a bunch of anchor tags (+- 1000). From all these tags there are a bunch that are just "trash" and +- 350 of tags that I would like to extract. All these tags look almost the same but the only difference is that the tags that I need have a "> Somebody's name<\a>" at the end. I would like to exctract only the link of all the anchor tags with this characteristic.

Comment: Do you need to use beautifulsoup? If use an html parser that allows xpath expressions, this can be much easier. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915338/how-can-i-find-the-link-url-by-link-text-with-xpath)

Comment: @bunji, I don't need to use it. I just saw that online must people use beautifulsoup this is why I followed. I will check alternative ways, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see in the image the ones with info have an `href` attribute containing `format="info"` so you could use an attribute=value CSS selector of `[href*=format="info"]` , where the `*` indicates *contains*;  the attribute value contains the substring after the first equals.

```
import bs4 , requests

res = requests.get("http://kern.humdrum.org/search?s=t&keyword=Haydn")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
for link in soup.select('[href*=format="info"]'):
    print(link.getText(), link['href'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way is using text attribute when printing the link. like this : 
`print link.text`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a list of the substrings you need to search for, you can do something like:

```
for link in containers:
    text = link.get_text().lower()
    if any(text.endswith(substr) for substr in substring_list):
        print(link)
        print('---')
```

Comment: This would not do what I need. The whole point of me scraping the page is to try to automatic grab all the links. If I filter for "allegro", this would be only one link.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do then. That loop printed a whole bunch of anchor tags for me. Could you provide more context about your problem?

Comment: Sure. At this point, I have a bunch of anchor tags (+- 1000). From all these tags there are a bunch that are just "trash" and +- 350 of tags that I would like to extract. All these tags look almost the same but the only difference is that the tags that I need have a "> Somebody's name<\a>" at the end. I would like to exctract only the link of all the anchor tags with this characteristic.

Comment: So in other words, you need to find all tags whose text ends with a certain substring? Or are there multiple different substrings you need to search for?

Comment: There are multiple substrings that I need to search for. For example, it could be "Allegro con brio" or "Presto" or... The only way to identify this tag is in the end of the tag I would have something like  "> Somebody's name<\a>" (i.e.  "> Presto<\a>")

Answer (score 0):

you want to extract link with specified anchor text?

```
for container in containers:
    link = container
    # match exact
    #if 'Allegro di molto' == link.text:
    if 'Allegro' in link.text: # contain
        print(link)
        print("---")
```